# Back button on Android saves contact instead of returning to app

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

I've set up an application that uses cordova to create a new contact. I created a custom Cordova plugin for this, and it is done through starting an Intent to open the Contact creation screen and populating some of the fields on it. However, when the back button is pressed when on this screen, instead of going back to the app, the contact get saved. Is this intended behavior somehow and is there a way to stop it?

The code that starts up the contact creation screen looks like this:

```
private void createContact(String fullname, String phone, String company) {
    Context context=this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK); 
    i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, fullname);
    i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phone);
    i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY, company);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the create contact screen of the OS?

Comment: @Anoop Yes, the intent starts up the native create contact screen and fills in some fields

Comment: Why do you need the Intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`? Can you try removing the flag and watch the behavior. As per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK), you should provide a way for the user to go back to the tasks you have launched.

Comment: @ManishMulimani I removed it, but the behavior stays the same. Only when I choose to explicitely discard the changes does it go back to the app correctly, the back button still saves the contact.

Comment: This seems to be the standard behavior, at least for the Google apps that handle `ACTION_INSERT` or `ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT`. For example, the Contacts and Calendar app work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's intended behavior. You can check in the source code of the Contacts application.

From the [manifest](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) we can determine that the activity that handles this intent is [`ContactEditorActivity`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/activities/ContactEditorActivity.java). Internally it uses a [`ContactEditorFragment`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/editor/ContactEditorFragment.java), which handles almost everything.

When you press the save button, the code executed is

```
        View saveMenuItem = customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.save_menu_item);
        saveMenuItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mFragment.doSaveAction();
            }
        });
```

And the implementation for `doSaveAction()` in the Fragment class is:

```
public void doSaveAction() {
    save(SaveMode.CLOSE);
}
```

The point you're probably interested in is that the Activity's `onBackPressed()` **also** saves.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mFragment.save(SaveMode.CLOSE);
}
```

So, basically, saving and exiting executes exactly the same code.

**Note:** I supposed the problem (from your point of view) is that the contact is saved. About the "not returning to the app" part, the answer is much simpler: just remove the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` flags.

[`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) instructs Android to start the Activity in a new task, which runs completely independent from the app that launched it (hence, it won't return to it when back is pressed).